# Is (or was) there a school of Islam that accepts both Sunni and Shia hadiths?

Tags: hadith, history, authenticity, school

I am asking if such a movement ever appeared, that would consider as authentic a hadith if it is considered authentic by either Sunni or Shia Muslims. In other words, the set of hadiths they consider authentic would be the union of the set of hadiths other schools consider authentic.

Was/is there any such a movement?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @G.Bach I think because of low quality. I updated it with proper grammar and formatting.

Comment: You are forgetting that Khawarij and Ibadi were earlier than sunnis or shi'a (at least as jursiprudence school) and they also have their hadith sources. And you forget that shi'a don't reject hadiths of sunnis per se but they accept only a few narrators among the sahaba and you forget however sunnis don't consider the shi'a Imams as infallible they consider them scholars and approve a lot of their views. And you might find out that sunnis have more or less the same amount of ahadith from ahl al-bayt as shi'a when it comes to connected chains (hadith musnad).